# Google Script Optional Parameter Not Working

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

I want to write a dice function that accepts multiple different inputs and can make sense of each of them, for example: `"1d20"`, `"1,20"`, and `"20"`.

I want to be able to pass either a string similar to the first two examples or the numbers as separate parameters, which is working well. The problem occurs when I try to pass it the single number. I would prefer the optional parameter to come first.

```js
function dice(quan, top) {
  var ct = 0, upd = 0;

  if (top === undefined) {
    upd = Math.max(quan.indexOf(","), quan.indexOf("d"));

    if (upd < 1) { //pass single parameter, eg. '20' for 1d20. Not working
      top = quan;
      quan = 1;
    } else {
      top = quan.slice(upd + 1, quan.length + 1);
      quan = quan.slice(0, upd);
    }
  } 

  for (ct = 0, upd = 0; ct < quan; ct++) {
    upd += Math.ceil(Math.random() * top);
  }

  return upd;
}
```

Comment: what is the result of ` "1d20","1,20", and "20"`?

Comment: a random number between 1 and 20. It simulates a die roll. But "20" gives #ERROR

Answer (score 1):

You could split by `d` or comma and map the numbers and check the length.

```js
function getParts(string) {
    var p = string.split(/[d,]/).map(Number);
    return p.length === 1
        ? [1, p[0]]
        : p;
}

console.log(["1d20", "1,20", "20"].map(getParts));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The first line returns an error. Is it the => ? I thought that could only be used when the rest was on the same line? new to this language

Comment: not you cound take an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in more than one line. i changed the function to a classic function.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work with Google Scripts, but I like where you went with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays instead like suggested by @Nine Scholz, this is what I've got:

```
function dice(val) {
  var ct = 0, upd = 0, str, top, quan;

  if (val + 0 == val) {
    quan = 1;
    top = val;
  } else {
    str = val.replace("d",",").split(",");
    quan = str[0];
    top = str[1];
  }

  if (isNaN(quan)||isNaN(top)) {
    return "NaN";
  }

  for (ct = 0,upd = 0; ct < quan; ct++) {
    upd += Math.ceil(Math.random() * top);
  }
  return upd;
}
```